# Denoising gravitational waves with autoencoders

Tags: time-series, autoencoder

I have read the following document and making some experiment with a synthetic dataset:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09919

I am not really sure of what format the author means for the autoencoder input.
I am working with Keras and Tensorflow and build a tensor with dimensions:

(samples,timesteps,features)

So I have tried to build the following features for each sample (this is for 8 points):

```
 [0  0  0  0  0  0 x1 x2
 0  0  0  0  0 x1 x2 x3
 0  0  0  0 x1 x2 x3 x4
 0  0  0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
 0  0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
 0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8
x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8  0
x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8  0  0
x4 x5 x6 x7 x8  0  0  0
x5 x6 x7 x8  0  0  0  0
x6 x7 x8  0  0  0  0  0
x7 x8  0  0  0  0  0  0
x8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I think this is also mentioned in the following article:

https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/archive_papers/interspeech_2012/i12_0022.pdf

The issue is that the results I am getting are very poor and the time series is denoised only a little and only if I use long sliding window.
The following is a snapshot:

[signal and denoised time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgfHc.jpg)

Does anyone understand how to properly format input?